# Dojo - Listen for DOM dijit/form/button click event within Widget

Tags: dom, widget, dojo, event-listener

I'm adding widgets to a ERSI map viewer project that can be found at this [link](https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/ConfigurableViewerJSAPI).

So I've made a query widget with a dijit/form/button and want to implement a dojo/on event listener to listen for its click event.

The button is declared in html markup as:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="searchButton" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Within my JavaScript, at the end of the postCreate function I have:

```
on(dojo.byId("searchButton"), "click", function execute() {
    // Set the WHERE search text
    this.findParams.searchText = dojo.byId("searchText").value;
    // Sends a request to the ArcGIS REST map service resource to perform a search based
    // on the FindParameters specified in the findParameters argument. On completion, the
    // onComplete event is fired and the optional callback function is invoked.
    this.findTask.execute(this.findParams, this.showResults, this.showError);
});
```

I'm receiving a TypeError: _526 is null. The error seems negligible as I know I'm doing this incorrectly. Aside from the above code I've tried dozens of others and nothing has worked.

And all the examples I've found for [dojo/on](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html#dojo-on) do not show how to perform this specific application.

I'm pretty new to dojo and I'm only on this project until I can solve a few issues another colleague is having, but if anyone could show me an example or link to an example that shows how to listen for a DOM dijit event within a widget it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED CODE AFTER ANSWER:**

I changed the code a bit, if the next person finds useful:

```
on(this.submitButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, 'execute'));
```

Where execute is the same function listed before, but to make this line a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your query widget is a Templated widget and also mixes in the WidgetsInTemplateMixin.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html#dijit-templatedmixin

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html#dijit-widgetsintemplatemixin

And the html that you have posted is in the widget template.  Your best option is not to use id.  By using id, you will only be able to have one of these widgets on a page.  That may be ok for your use case, but isn't a good practice.  Instead, use `data-dojo-attach-point`.

```
<div>
    ... MORE HTML...
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
        data-dojo-attach-point="submitButton" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

In your code, you can then reference `submitButton` as a variable of the widget.

```
on(this.submitButton, "click", function execute() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. That was my error when posting the question. The code is actually using the correct html code you highlighted. Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: You were correct, it is a Templated widget that does mixin the WidgetsInTemplateMixin. Your answer was spot on and worked beautifully. Thanks for the explanation as well.

Comment: +1 for me... I didn't realize the html was actually in the widget template. I leave my answer though, as it may add some info...

Answer (score 0):

Since your button itself is a widget, you don't need dojo/on to intercept the click event.

Assuming you put "dijit/registry" in the list of your widget's dependencies, try :

```
registry.byId("searchButton").on("click", function execute() {
    // Set the WHERE search text
    this.findParams.searchText = dojo.byId("searchText").value;
    // Sends a request to the ArcGIS REST map service resource to perform a search based
    // on the FindParameters specified in the findParameters argument. On completion, the
    // onComplete event is fired and the optional callback function is invoked.
    this.findTask.execute(this.findParams, this.showResults, this.showError);
});
```

The reason why you are having the error is because when you do...

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="searchButton" type="button">Submit</button>
```

... you create a widget whose id is "searchButton". The node itself though does not have that id anymore when the widget template is rendered. Therefore you cannot reference it through dom.byId.

If you want a reference to the widget's domNode, you need to do :

```
registry.byId("searchButton").domNode
```

If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/XaK5Q/), you will see that the Button domNode doesn't have an id at all. If now you look at the html of that button in Firebug or in your browser console, you will notice that the domNode has an attribute "widgetid=btn2" rather than "id=btn2".